# System has not been booted with systemd

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm trying to follow the jenkins installation process as discuss in this article of digital ocean, in WSL. The Ubuntu version installed is Ubuntu 18.04.

Everything in jenkins installation is fine but when I tried to run this sudo systemctl start jenkins I got this message.

`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

Any Idea on what should I do with that?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this was asked, but for the sake of others looking at this question:

systemd doesn't run on WSL, it instead uses a different init system. Use the `service` command in place of `systemctl` (e.g. replace `systemctl status <service_name>` with `service <service_name> status`, in your case replacing `<service_name>` with `jenkins`).

Here's some more info:
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/system-not-booted-with-systemd-as-init.html

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of WSL do support systemd. In my case, I only needed to do `wsl --update`, and then reboot.
For details, check [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate/1379567#1379567).